# Ionic Cordova CLI failures on build ios command - "Module not found, can't resolve..."

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to run ionic cordova build ios and am consistently met with the following:

```
Error: ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ionic-native/file' in '/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/src/app'
resolve '@ionic-native/file' in '/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/src/app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@ionic-native/file)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file doesn't exist
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file]
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file.ts]
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file.js]
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file.json]
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/file]
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 23:0-42
 @ ./src/app/main.ts,./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ionic-native/photo-library' in '/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/src/app'
resolve '@ionic-native/photo-library' in '/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/src/app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library doesn't exist
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library]
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library.ts]
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library.js]
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library.json]
[/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic-native/photo-library]
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 28:0-59
 @ ./src/app/main.ts
    at new BuildError (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at callback (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:121:28)
    at emitRecords.err (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:269:13)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:375:38)
    at emitAssets.err (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:262:10)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:368:12)
    at next (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:222:13)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (/Users/justinfrevert/Desktop/AceAdz-App/app-copy/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:365:9)
```

This did not occur after a code change. This started occurring after a separate error that I was trying to correct: the compiler complaining about improper types being passed into the watchPosition() method from ionic native geolocation. That was a separate issue also caused by version changes - so I tried to revert the version back from the latest to 3.14.0. that was what gave the above mentioned error. I then reverted to 3.11.0, because that was the original version I had it on when it was working. I tried to build, and it still did not work. I then switched back to the latest version, but still got the above error. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the cordova and npm packages for geolocation, still no dice. Please let me know what I might be able to do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have latest version so make sure you have all the latest cordova and npm packages installed. After this please remove the ios platform and than again add this.Also, make sure that there are engine entries in your config.xml for all your platforms of interest. This guarantees that your are using the exact platform tool versions that you’re using locally. I think instances where the platform tool versions specified in the config.xml are incompatible with the project and needed to be either upgraded or downgraded.

Comment: I tried re adding the platform and was met with this:

Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "platforms". Please try adding it again.

I checked in the plugins and there was no plugin by the name of "platforms". I googled this and couldn't find anything helpful. I think i might make a new post for this issue.